# Node, Electron, ExcelJS, leer un archivo CSV dentro de una funcion

Tags: javascript, nodejs, electron

Intento leer un archivo CSV con node, electron y exceljs, este es el codigo:

```
var workbook = new Excel.Workbook();

let button = document.getElementById('button')
button.addEventListener('click', read, false)

async function read(){
    await workbook.csv.readFile("Excel.csv")
   .then(val => console.log(val))
}
```

Pero la consola no muestra ninguna respuesta, que ocurre?
Muchas gracias por las respuestas.

Comment: ¿Devuelve `undefined` o es que no encuentra el fichero?

Comment: No, simplemente la consola no muestra nada y el fichero esta en la misma ruta del proyecto, lo lee por que me devuelve (promise {<pending>}, y utilzo el then para resolverla, pero no muestra nada.

Comment: Estás usando `await` en conjunto con `then`. Por ello no te muestra el resultado. O usas `await` o usas `then`, pero no ambos. Por favor consultar la [documentación](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs#reading-csv). El método que usas no te va a devolver un valor que quieras mostrar por consola, te devolverá un objeto de tipo `worksheet`. El uso correcto con `await` sería: `const myworksheet = await workbook.csv.readFile("Excel.csv");` Luego ya podrás usar tu variable `myworksheet` de acuerdo a lo que necesites. Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias @MauricioContreras efectivamente ese era el error.
sin embargo si intento llamar esa función desde un boton en el HTML no me muestra nada, pero si llamo la funcion desde el JS si imprime en consola.